# regex to get strings before and after the colon

Tags: java, regex

I am having string like following

```
olah billo:78517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, jiglo piglo:68517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, nimho james:98517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, kathy ruck:38517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec
```

I want to have a regex to get the string before and after colon in a Map with key the string after colon. I want to know what is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is the simplest way (Pseudo-code):

- Split the string on comma. That will give you an array containing each `:` separated string.
- Create a `Map<String, String>`
- Iterate over the array

  - For each element in array, split on colon `":"`. This will again give you an array. Let's name it `arr`.
  - Add an entry in the map, with key as `arr[0]` and value as `arr[1]`. Trim the leading and trailing whitespace as needed. Or make the first split on comma followed by 0 or more spaces - `,\s*`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` to split string with **comma** and **colon**.

```
String str = "olah billo:78517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, jiglo piglo:68517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, nimho james:98517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, kathy ruck:38517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec";
            String[] splitComma = str.split(",");
            String[] splitColon = splitComma[0].split(":");
            HashMap<String, String> finlMapArr = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < splitComma.length; j++) {
                 splitColon = splitComma[j].split(":");
                finlMapArr.put(splitColon[0] , splitColon[1]);
            }

            System.out.println(finlMapArr);
```